# Implicit cast from function to function pointer?

Tags: c++, function, function-pointers

I have a function that accepts as an argument a function pointer. Surprisingly, I can pass in both a function pointer and an ordinary function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

int triple(int a) {
    return 3*a;
}

int apply(int (*f)(int), int n) {
    return f(n);
}

int main() {
    std::cout << apply(triple, 7) << "\n";
    std::cout << apply(&triple, 7) << "\n";
}
```

I'm confused about why this works. Is there an implicit conversion from functions to function pointers?

Comment: And, because of the way the address and dereferencing rules work for functions, you could also use `&&f`, `&&&f`, etc., with as many &’s as you like. Similarly, in `apply`, you could write `(*f)(n)`, `(**f)(n)`, etc.

Comment: @PeteBecker Where can I learn more about this? Does this work for C as well?

Comment: @LoverofStructure -- first, `&&` won't work; it's the logical and operator. That should have been `& &f`, `& & &f`, etc. This is just a quirk of the grammar. It's not actually useful. Yes, it's the same in C.

Comment: @PeteBecker 1. I can't get the OP's code above to work with `& &triple`, but it does work with `return (******f)(n);`. 2. Where in the C and C++ standards documents can I learn about such behavior? (I assume that there are certain environments in which `f` "decays" to `*f` or `&f`.)

Comment: @PeteBecker I found it (for C) in the discussion of *function designators*. However, did you mean `&f`, `&*&f`, `&*&*&f` instead? I can't figure out a way to use indefinitely repeated ampersands.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, there's [function-to-pointer implicit conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Function_to_pointer):

> An lvalue of function type T can be implicitly converted to a prvalue [pointer to that function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_functions). This does not apply to non-static member functions because lvalues that refer to non-static member functions do not exist.

And

> A pointer to function can be initialized with an address of a non-member function or a static member function. Because of the function-to-pointer implicit conversion, the address-of operator is optional:
>
> ```
> void f(int);
> void (*p1)(int) = &f;
> void (*p2)(int) = f; // same as &f
> ```

That means when being used in context requiring a function pointer, function (except for non-static member function) would convert to function pointer implicitly, and the usage of `operator&` is optional.