# Implicit function-to-function-pointer conversion not working for std containers (e.g. vector)

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I've recently learned that C++ can perform [implicit function-to-function-pointer cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54357936/) whenever it found necessary. For example, in my example below, `my_func_1` and `my_func_2` are equivalent. However, `vector_1` and `vector_2` are not, and in fact, `vector_2` will give a compile error. Similar compile errors also happen for other standard containers, e.g. `unordered_map`. Why is it so?

```cpp
class my_class {
    // dummy class
};

int main() {
    vector<my_class(*)()> vector_1; // correct one
    vector<my_class()> vector_2;    // gives compile error
    
    // However, both of the below are OK due to implicit
    // function-to-function-pointer conversion
    void my_func_1(my_class(*)());
    void my_func_2(my_class());    // equivalent to the one above
}
```

Here is the compile error message (shortened to highlight the error):

> /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/ext/new_allocator.h:96:7: error: multiple overloads of 'address' instantiate to the same signature '__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<my_class ()>::const_pointer (__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<my_class ()>::const_reference) const noexcept' (aka 'my_class (*(my_class (&)()) const noexcept)()')
> address(const_reference __x) const _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
> ^
> /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/allocator.h:112:30: note: in instantiation of template class '__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<my_class ()>' requested here
> class allocator : public __allocator_base<_Tp>
> ^
> /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/ext/alloc_traits.h:49:47: note: in instantiation of template class 'std::allocator<my_class ()>' requested here
> template<typename _Alloc, typename = typename _Alloc::value_type>
> ^
> /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_vector.h:83:35: note: in instantiation of default argument for '__alloc_traits<std::allocator<my_class ()>>' required here
> typedef typename __gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<_Alloc>::template
> ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_vector.h:386:30: note: in instantiation of template class 'std::_Vector_base<my_class (), std::allocator<my_class ()>>' requested here
> class vector : protected _Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>
> ^
> Line 7: Char 24: note: in instantiation of template class 'std::vector<my_class (), std::allocator<my_class ()>>' requested here
> vector<my_class()> vector_2;    // gives compile error
> ^
> /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/ext/new_allocator.h:92:7: note: previous declaration is here
> address(reference __x) const _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
> ^

Comment: The conversion doesn't happen everywhere. As you noticed, it happens in function parameters, but not in template parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this declaration:

```
vector<my_class()> vector_2;
```

the type used to instantiate the vector is `myclass()`, which is a function type. Specifically it's a function that takes no arguments, and returns a `my_class`.

A function type is not *copy-assignable*, as can be seen from this test:

```
static_assert(not std::is_copy_assignable_v<Foo()>);
```

Being *copy-assignable* is one of the requirements on the type used as a template parameter for `std::vector`, and so this declaration doesn't compile.

---

The remaining declarations are fine:

```
vector<my_class(*)()> vector_1; // vector of function pointer type
```

Due to implicit conversion to function-pointers of types used in function parameters, the following declarations are equivalent:

```
void my_func_1(my_class(*)());  // function taking a function pointer 
                                // to a function that takes no arguments
                                // and returns a my_class

void my_func_2(my_class());     // function taking a function that takes no 
                                // arguments and returns a my_class
```

Comment: No it is not a function type `my_class()` but it is just an r-value of type `my_class`.

Comment: Here is an example that proves that `my_class()` is not a function type: `    decltype(myclass()) a;
    a.foo();` we assume that `my_class` has a member function called `foo`  then this call succeeds.

Comment: @Maestro No, it's a function type. `my_class{}` would be an r-value of type `my_class`. Compare the different error [messages](https://godbolt.org/z/3c8cr5). Only the second one has a type/value mismatch.

Comment: Have you used `decltype(my_calss())`?

Comment: @Maestro I have. Are you asking why in `decltype(my_class())`, the `my_class()` is not treated as a function type?

Comment: So `decltype(my_class)` returns the return type of  an un-named function that returns a `my_class` type and takes 0 argument. is it correct?

Comment: @Maestro No problem. To clarify, "most vexing parse" applies to cases where if the compiler could treat an expression as a function declaration, it will. Inside `decltype` that doesn't apply.

Comment: Yes get it thank you for the useful information. It was really misleading to me.

Comment: @Maestro No worries, it can get tricky :) To answer the last comment, `decltype(my_class)` won't even compile, because `my_class` is not an expression, it's a type.

Comment: Yes I know it . Because `decltype`  works on expressions not types e.g: `decltype (int)` won't work. right?

Comment: One last thing: `decltype(my_class())` does it mean the type returned from an un-named function? and that return type is itself of type `my_class`?

Comment: @Maestro Ok, definitely the last question I'm going to answer here :) No, it's exactly `my_class` because `decltype` will treat `my_class()` as an expression that is a direct-initialization of an object of type `my_class`. Of course, `decltype` is an unevaluated context so no object is actually created, but that is the type that you'll get.

Comment: So `decltype my_class()` or `decltype (my_class{})` are identical and it is evaluating a direct-init temporary of type `my_class`? (in fact without evaluating it)

Comment: Thank you so much for your useful information and help.

Comment: Thank you all for your help! It's my first time asking a question on stackoverflow. Do you know why I received 2 down votes instantly? I will edit my question so that it becomes more useful for the audience.

Comment: @user2709246 Actually, your question is pretty good. Don't let down-votes get you down too much. Sometimes users will down-vote without even reading the question fully, especially if the user is new. One thing that would be an improvement is if you added the compiler error message you got.

Comment: @cigien Thanks so much. I just added the error message. I learned a lot from you today!

Comment: @user2709246 No problem, happy to help :) Yes, the added error message improves the question considerably. Now you know at least one more thing to get right before posting next time. Good luck :)