# Why can I assign to a function pointer both a reference to a function a the function itself?

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers

I'm trying to understand function pointers in C.

I've defined this type:

`typedef int (*bin_op_ptr)(int, int);`

which I think should be a pointer to a function taking two `int` parameters and return a `int`.

Then I've defined a simple function, with this prototype:

`int min(int a, int b);`

I've noticed that I can do both

`bin_op_ptr min_ptr1 = min;`
and
`bin_op_ptr max_ptr2 = &min;`

and I am a little bit lost.

Why is it possible to assign both `min` and a reference to `min` to my variables with the same type?

If I have a pointer to Integer I can only assign a reference to integer, not the integer itself.

Is there something I'm misunderstanding about how C function pointers work?

Comment: In `bin_op_ptr min_ptr1 = min` the function (`min`) decays to a pointer.

Comment: I believe that using a function name is already a reference to a function --- thus &min and min are the same value.  You could test this by printing the pointer you get.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Implicit cast from function to function pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54357936/implicit-cast-from-function-to-function-pointer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty much an exact duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54357936/implicit-cast-from-function-to-function-pointer)

The answer is that functions can be implicitly converted to function pointers (similar to array to pointer decay) per the spec.